# Field with removed 'required' attribute keeps validating after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, required

I have a form to submit several fields. Two of them are for changing a password.

These password fields aren't required to be filled out before submitting. However, if one of them isn't blank I add the required attribute to both fields when it's changed through jQuery. I remove the attributes when I empty one and the other is already empty too.

The thing it seems to work the most of the times with an exception:

1. I fill out **password**
2. **password2** is blank
3. I submit the form

In this case the validation for **password2** shows up, but if I want to remove everything and submit, I can't:

4. I remove **password**
5. I submit the form again
6. The validation for **password2** shows up again. Even if the 'required' attributed is removed in the HTML source

This is the HTML code:

```
<form id="edicionPerfilForm" action="actor/edit.do" method="post">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
         <div>
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input id="password" name="password" class="form-control" type="password" value="" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Fill out this field')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
            <br>    
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
         <div>
            <label for="password2">Repeat password</label>
            <input id="password2" name="password2" class="form-control" type="password" value="" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Fill out this field')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">    
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <button name="save" type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Send</button>
</form>
```

And the jQuery code:

```
$('#password').change(function() {
        if($(this).val() != ''){
            $(this).attr('required', true);
            $( '#password2' ).attr('required', true);
        }else{
            if($('#password2').val() == ''){
                $(this).removeAttr('required');
                $( '#password2' ).removeAttr('required');
            }           
        }
    });
    $('#password2').change(function() {
        if($(this).val() != ''){
            $(this).attr('required', true);
            $('#password').attr('required', true);
        }else{
            if($('#password').val() == ''){
                $(this).removeAttr('required');
                $('#password').removeAttr('required');
            }           
        }
    });
```

And it's an example in JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jke3pgh0/

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you a different approach here...

First, you only need one handler for this, since the logic is the same for both inputs. You can use more than one selector... Ex: `$('#password, #password2')`. But I would use a class instead... Like `$(".password")`. It's up to you.

Second, I said the *«logic is the same»*... **That is**:

> If one of the two inputs is not empty, both are required.

So having the same `change` event handler on both inputs mean you don't really know which one triggered the event. So I suggest to use an [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) loop here (to make sure you check all values)... and a boolean *"flag"* (true/false).

After that loop, use that *"flag"* to set the `required` attribute.

*I used a CSS rule to make the result obvious in the snippet below.*

```js
$('#password, #password2').change(function(){
  
  // Look up for the password inputs in that "row".
  var pass_inputs = $(this).closest(".row").find("[type='password']");
  
  // Flag to determine if at least one is not empty.
  var not_empty = false;
  
  // Loop throug the password inputs and change the flag.
  pass_inputs.each(function(){
    if($(this).val() != ''){
    not_empty = true
    }
  });
  
  // Use the flag as the boolean argument for the required attribute.
  pass_inputs.attr('required', not_empty);
});
```

```css
[required]{
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="edicionPerfilForm" action="actor/edit.do" method="post">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <div>
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input id="password" name="password" class="form-control" type="password" value="" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Fill out this field')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">
        <br>    
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <div>
        <label for="password2">Repeat password</label>
        <input id="password2" name="password2" class="form-control" type="password" value="" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Fill out this field')" oninput="this.setCustomValidity('')">    
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button name="save" type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Send</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem since once you submit fullfilling one input, the validation for the other one is always remaining. It works in the same way I did with the exception of the CSS part

Comment: Do you use `.validate()`? If yes, you can [ignore](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#ignore) fields based on a class...